# Facebook/MVC2 integration

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-2

So you know when you sign onto Facebook and you see your news feed, and say theres an update from someone that says like,

> "This technology is so cool!" posted
>   via SelectiveTweets (logo)

How can I achieve this functionality for my website, so users can go to my site, and whatever comment they write on my site, will get posted to their Facebook wall as well, with my little tagline and small logo. Do I need to pay for that or is that available in their free API?

I know how to connect to their API, and do all the basic stuff, but it was this specific functionality I was inquiring about.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like SelectiveTweets is just plain authorized to both read your tweets and post to your wall. No?

Comment: Well the functionality I am looking for is, someone comes onto my site, logs into their facebook through the facebook api, and then comments on something, and w/e they comment will also get posted on their facebook wall.

Comment: This is normally done using the method I described. C.f. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

Comment: Put that as an answer bzlm and I'll accept. The API is definitely what I need.

Comment: Ok. :) Let us know if you need more specific help. But I think there are questions here already on how to achieve each portion of what you need (write an application, request authorization, store an access token, use the Graph API, etc).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> "This technology is so cool!" posted
>   via SelectiveTweets (logo)

This means that the user in question has **authorized the SelectiveTweets application to post to their wall**, and that the application has then actually posted to the wall on the user's behalf [using the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). In this case, I suspect the application subscribes to the user's tweets, and posts them to their wall if they match a certain criterion.

In your case, **you would still need an application that requests permission to post to the user's wall**, and then you would do that whenever a user who has enabled your application makes a comment on your web site. Your application would live on your web site and use an access token to make wall posts on the user's behalf.